# Unable to store cookies and allow session

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple ticketing app.

Once the user logins it should show a dashboard with project name and 3 categories of tickets count and a add ticket button to add a new ticket

**Problem** I'm able to authenticate the user on login screen but when it navigates to the next screen that is dashboard the user get unauthenticated hence not able to fetch api and display the data being sent

index.js

```
var app = angular.module("loginTest", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // login view definition
        .when("/login", {
            controller: "loginController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "login.html"
        })

        .when("/main", {
            controller: "mainController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "main.html",
            authenticated:true
        })
        .when("/setting", {
            controller: "settingController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "project.html",
            authenticated:true
        })
        .when("/about", {
            controller: "aboutController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "about.html",
            authenticated:true
        })
        .when("/addTicket",{
            controller:"addTicketCtrl",
            controllerAs:"vm",
            templateUrl:"addTicket.hmtl",
            authenticated:true
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/main",
            authenticated:true
        });
});

app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next) {
        // check current login status and filter out if navigating to login
        if (!$rootScope.loggedIn && next.originalPath !== "/login") {
            // remember the original url
            $location.url("/login?back=" + $location.url());
        }
    });
});

app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

app.service("loginService",$cookies, function ($http, $cookies) {

    console.log("service");
    $cookies.get(email),
    $cookies.get(password)
    return {
        checkLogin: function () {
            return $http.post("/login").then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
            });
        },
        login: function (email, pass, $cookies) {
            console.log("loginn fucntion");
            return $http.post("https://qa.workdaysync.io/getcadentapi/auth/login", {
                email: email,
                password : pass,


            }).then(function (response) {
                //console.log("1st response"+response.status);
                return response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                var err = new Error(response.statusText);
                //console.log("2st response" +response.errorCode);
                err.code = response.status;
                if (response.status == 401) {
                    var error = "USERNAME OR PASSWORD IS INCORRECT"
                    var loginfailed = true;
                    //alert(error);
                    //console.log(loginfailed);
                }
                throw err;
            });
        }
    };
})
/* app.service("addTicketService",function($rootScope,$http){
    var vm=this;
    addTicket: function (description){
        return $http.post("https://qa.workdaysync.io/getcadentapi/tickets", {
            description: description,
            id: name
        }).then(function (response) {
            //console.log("1st response"+response.status);
            return response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        }

})
}); */
app.controller("loginController",$cookies, function ($rootScope, $location, loginService,$cookies) {
    var vm = this;

    function success() {
        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        $rootScope.loginError = false;
        $cookies.put('username', email);
        $cookies.put('password', password);
        var back = $location.search().back || "";
        $location.url(back !== "/login" ? back : "");/* 
        $cookies.put('username', email);
        $cookies.put('password', password); */


    }

    function failure() {
        $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
        $rootScope.loginError = true;
    }

    loginService.checkLogin().then(success);

    vm.login = function () {
        loginService.login(vm.user, vm.pass).then(success, failure);
    };

    vm.logout = function () {
        loginService.logut(
            localStorage.clear(),
            sessionStorage.clear()
        );
    }
})
app.service('HttpService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getPost: function () {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise.
            return $http.get('https://qa.workdaysync.io/getcadentapi/sync')
                .then(function (response) {
                    // In the response, resp.data contains the result. Check the console to see all of the data returned.
                    console.log('Get Post', response);
                    return response.data;
                });
        },
        getUsers: function () {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise.
            return $http.get('https://qa.workdaysync.io/getcadentapi/sync')
                .then(function (response) {
                    // In the response, resp.data contains the result. Check the console to see all of the data returned.
                    console.log('Get Users', response);
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    }
});
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, HttpService) {
    HttpService.getPost()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.post = response;
        });
    HttpService.getUsers()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.users = response;
            console.log("asdfdsfsdf");
            console.log("umm"+ $scope.users.inProgressCount);
            console.log("asdfdsfsdf++++sdsad");
            var myNumber =  $scope.users.inProgressCount;
            var formattedNumber = ("0" + myNumber).slice(-2);
            console.log(formattedNumber);
        });
});
app.filter('counterValue', function(){
    return function(value){
      value = parseInt(value);
       if(!isNaN(value) && value >= 0 && value < 10)
          {return "0"+ value;
       return "";
    }else{
        return value;
        return "";
    }
    }
 })
```

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var session = require("express-session");

var app = express();

app.use(express.static("app"));
app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: '1234567qwerty',
    signed: true,
  }));
app.use(session({
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 10
    },
    resave: false,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "COOKIE_SECRET"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/login", function (req, res, _next) {
    console.log(req.session.id);
    var email = req.body.email;
    var pass = req.body.pass;
    if (email == req.session.user && pass == req.session.pass) {
        res.status(401).end();
        console.log("Inside login else logic" + req.body.email);

    } else {
        req.session.user = req.body.email;
        req.session.password = req.body.password;
        console.log("Inside login if logic" + req.body.email);
        res.end();
    }
});

app.get("/me", function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.id);
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.send(req.session.user);
    } else {
        res.status(405).end();
        console.log("status");
    }
});

var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("Sample login server running");
});
```

It should login and then display the ticket raised count and when clicked on add ticket button the cookie should be valid

Comment: WHat errors does the setting of cookies give? And are you setting them to be read from the same server that served the page that sets them?

Comment: I'm very very very new to this so whatever suits best will be helpful thanks in advance.

Comment: Also you are passing `'$cookies'` and not `$cookies` in your app controller

Comment: unexpected token found . it keeps on giving this error

Comment: Don't quote the $cookies. Click on the error in the console to see where in the code it is

Comment: unexpected token issue solved, thanks, now to main problem session maintaining

Comment: Please rewrite the question with explanation of other issue.

Comment: I've bolded the main issue.

Comment: I've made the suggested changes

Comment: I do not see the server.js accessing the cookies anywhere - I am not familiar with angular but still I would expect a read of the cookies but instead see `resave: false,`

Comment: So technically resae: true; should do it?

Comment: I have no idea. As I said, I do not do angular or express

Comment: Can u mention someone from your network who knows? it'll be a great help thanks.

Comment: That does not work here. A good explanation does and your question was voted up too

Comment: No answers yet :(((